# Is a class inherited from another class larger in memory than a class which uses no inheritence?

Tags: c#, memory, inheritance, object, clr

Imagine I have two classes, class1 and class2.

Class1 inherits from baseClass, which looks like so:

```
baseClass
{
private Int64 one;
protected Int64 two;
public Int64 three;
}
```

and class1 looks like this

```
Class1 : baseClass
{
private Int64 four;
protected Int64 five;
public Int64 six;
}
```

and class2 looks like this:

```
Class2
{
private Int64 one;
protected Int64 two;
public Int64 three;
private Int64 four;
protected Int64 five;
public Int64 six;
}
```

If I were to create arrays of 10k of each class, which would be larger? Would the class1 array be larger because class1 would also contain some sort of meta data to do with baseClass? Otherwise their properties are identical, so technically they should be the same.

Comment: Are you familiar with the sizeof keyword?

Comment: Ah of course! I can't believe I didn't think of that! I could never get the hang of wednesdays. I'll get on this right away and put the results up. Thanks!

Comment: @Brannon `sizeof` won't help with this. This is a reference type.

Comment: For this kind of thing you could use struct instead of class. With struct yo can use sizeof(). But I'm sorry to say that you cannot inherit structs.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382634/memory-allocation-for-a-class-that-has-deep-inheritance-in-net has a few answers around this area from some 'big hitters'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given two arrays of reference types, that is:

```
Class1[] a1 = new Class1[10000];
Class2[] a2 = new Class2[10000];
```

The arrays will be *exactly* the same size. The elements of the arrays are just references, and a reference is always the same size, regardless of the object to which it's referring. A reference is 4 bytes in the 32-bit runtime, and 8 bytes in the 64-bit runtime.

As for the class instances, I would expect them to be identical in size, as well. The class instance itself only holds the data for the class, and a small amount of other data that includes a reference to the type for that class. The class instance itself doesn't "know" that it's a derived class. That information is held by the type.

So, the *type* information for `Class1` might be slightly larger than the type information for `Class2`, but *instances* of those two classes will occupy the same amount of memory.

When all's said, using `Class1`, which inherits from `baseClass`, is going to cost you a handful of bytes more than using `Class2`, because you have type information for two classes. But it really is just a few bytes more--whatever the overhead is for the class metadata. It does not cost you anything extra for each class instance.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that the arrays would be the same. I was angling more towards total memory usage. I have an application where I will be creating ~1 million of these classes and need every bit I can get. So would you say that those couple of bits gain won't be per instance, so there's no need to wreck my currently beautiful inheritence?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. There should be no per-instance cost.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this only gives an overview of sizes relative to eachother. As far as I know there is no direct way to know runtime sizes.

```
baseClass bc = new baseClass();


Class1 class1 = new Class1();
Class2 class2 = new Class2();

long bcSize = 0;
long class1Size = 0;
long class2Size = 0;

using (Stream s = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, bc);
    bcSize = s.Length; //223
}

using (Stream s = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, class1);
    class1Size = s.Length; //298
}

using (Stream s = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, class2);
    class2Size = s.Length; //264
}
```

Comment: That has _nothing_ to do with the space consumed in memory.

Comment: @SLaks I do know, but this just to give an overview.

Comment: This doesn't even give an overview.  It's just completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using virtual methods the size will be the same.

when using virtual methods you will have an overhead of  bytes for a virtual table pointer in that class.

Comment: No; all .Net objects always have a vtable.

Comment: And the vtable is not allocated per-instance.